# Will hibernate increment version if I add/remove/update element of dependable collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, optimistic-locking

I am learning hibernate  optimistic lock mechanism and I haven't found answer on my question in [user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic)

Let's say we have entity like this:

```
@Entity
class Employee{
    @Version
    Long versionField;

    List<Employee> subordinates;
    ...

}
```

And somewhere we have following code:

```
Employee sub = ....
Emplyee emp = readEmploye();
emp.getSubordinates().add(sub);
```

Can I control of version incrementation at this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default no. Since you're not changing the entity, but rather other entities that are linked to it.

However it's possible to have that functionality, but it takes quite a bit of configuration and preferably planning in advance.
I'm not going to duplicate all the code from the honourable Vlad Mihalcea, [see here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-increment-the-parent-entity-version-whenever-a-child-entity-gets-modified-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Basically you need to use event listeners to intercept the save calls, and using a `RootAware` interface (not a Hibernate interface, just a helper) a child entity being saved knows its "root" and can use the `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` lock on its parent entity to increase its version.

---

Regarding data consistency: the flushing can fail if the child was modified or the parent was modified (or both were), but the `lock()` on the root entity makes sure that the operation is atomic. If the (pessimistic) lock on the root succeeds, and the (optimistic) lock on the child succeeds, the complete transaction succeeds. Thanks to the pessimistic lock, there's no chance of getting "half updates" that would corrupt the data.

Comment: Eventually I was able to read the article you lonked but I still have a question: hibernate generates 2 update statements. 1 - to update child and one more to update parent version if the version was not changed someone else. Lets imagine situation following sequence:

Comment: thread1: update child then thread2 updates child too then thread1 update parent version and then thread2 tries to update parent version but failed. Looks like at this case we will have some data inconsistency and it depends on isolation level. What do you think ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow There's no data inconsistency due to the lock taken on the parent entity during flush. With two threads one of those locks will fail, and the complete transaction will be rolled back. Isolation level has no effect here, because we're still on the ORM layer and not yet in the database.

Comment: so at this case we will have 2 TRANSACTIONS ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow tried to explain the flow a bit in my edit.

Comment: Oh, looks like I understand it wrong. but why just 2 parallel transactions is not enough?

Comment: @gstackoverflow because it's using optimistic locking. Otherwise you'd have to use a pessimistic lock, which in many cases wouldn't be a viable option. The "transaction" here is a bit misleading, since there's no database transaction with optimistic locking, but there's still a JPA transaction.

Comment: Oh, I am fully confused now. What is a JPA transaction? I would be happy if you explain flow in details

Comment: @gstackoverflow the optimistic lock acts like a light weight transaction using the version number. Pass/fail, nothing in between.

Comment: I understand common mechanism. It is the same like an atomic. But I expect that we need to use exclusive lock  during flush because we update several related entities

Comment: @gstackoverflow and we do, hence the pessimistic lock on the root entity.

Comment: looks like I don't understand what is a pessimistic lock on the root entity. What is   it exactly  ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow an exclusive lock, that guarantees that the code works and no data is garbled.

Comment: Is it database lock ? smth like select for update ?

Comment: That could be one implementation, but I doubt the spec defines how it needs to be implemented.

Comment: is this lock acquired before child entity update ? so if the child was changed the sequence is following - 1.lock parent, 2. update child 3. update parent(version) 4. unlock parent. is it correct ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow it's acquired during the flush in the interceptor, so yes.

Comment: Oh, I see private void incrementRootVersion(FlushEntityEvent event, Object root) {
        event.getSession().lock(root, LockMode.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
    }