# Optimistic locking version not updated in parent when child updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a Parent with an undirectional OneToMany Child relationship and optimistic locking via `@Version`.

When I edit the parent, when I add a child or when I remove a child, the version number is bumped and the optimistic locking is working.

My problem is when I edit a child itself, the parent version is not bumped, so the locking is not working. Is there a way to do it in a JPA or hibernate way automatically ?

All modifications of children go though the parent so I can technically detect them by setting my own version/dirty flag each time a method is called, but it doesn't sound a right solution for me.

I only want to have a version flag in Parent (it is the aggregate root). In my domain, children can't be edited directly, only via the parent, so it makes sense.

Using `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` doesn't works (neither will be triggered in case of child update).

Using `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` doesn't works. Here a code sample to reproduce the bug :

```java
// Main
var emFactory = buildFactory(); // Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ORM");
var em = emFactory.createEntityManager();

var transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
var parent = new Parent(
    1l, 0, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Child(1L, 1L, 10),
        new Child(2L, 1L, 20),
        new Child(3L, 1L, 30)
    ))
);
em.persist(parent);
transaction.commit();

// version is updated
// update Parent set value=1, version=1 where id=1 and version=0
transaction.begin();
parent.editParent();
transaction.commit();

// version is updated
// insert into Child (parentId, value, id) values (1, 40, 4)
// update Parent set value=1, version=2 where id=1 and version=1
// update Child set parentId=1 where id=4
transaction.begin();
parent.addChild(new Child(4L, 1L, 40));
transaction.commit();

// update Parent set value=1, version=3 where id=1 and version=2
// update Child set parentId=null where parentId=1 and id=1
transaction.begin();
parent.removeFirstChild();
transaction.commit();


// !!! version is NOT updated !!!
// update Child set parentId=1, value=21 where id=2
transaction.begin();
parent.editFirstChild();
transaction.commit();


// Parent
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public int value;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public List<Child> children;

    @Version
    public int version;

    public void editParent() {
        ++value;
    }

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void removeFirstChild() {
        this.children.remove(0);
    }

    public void editFirstChild() {
        ++children.get(0).value;
    }

    public Parent(Long id, int value, List<Child> children) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.children = children;
    }

}

// Child
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    Long id;

    Long parentId;

    int value;

    public Child(Long id, Long parentId, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381106/will-hibernate-increment-version-if-i-add-remove-update-element-of-dependable-co). You need to do it manually since a modification in a child is not a modification in a parent, so everything works as designed.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you, I saw this article and hoped for something simpler.

Comment: The solution in the answer linked solve a case where we have a bidirectionnal relationship (@ManyToOne) in our case the child doesn't know its parent so it can't notify it via hibernate hook (interceptor/integrator). There is still probably something to do at changedetection level or using theses hooks.