# Spring Data Rest with @Version from Parent-Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I set up a @Repository for an Entity with a @Version property and published it via @RepositoryRestResource which was pretty straight forward. The version is transfered to the and from the client in the Http Header as an ETag and it works perfectly.

In my current scenario I have a child Entity which doesn't have a @Version-Tag itself, instead the @Version-Tag of its parent has to be used. That means, that every change of the child or the parent has to increment the parent version. Also the operation should fail, if the parent version is outdated. For this case EntityManager offers the LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT.

How do I customize Spring Data Rest to implement such behavior? Do I have to implement a @RestController from scratch?

----------------- edit ----------------

Here is a small example i set up which works for a simple entity

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    public static class ServerConfiguration
    {
        private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    
        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
        {
            if (emf == null)
            {
                Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
                properties.put(AvailableSettings.CLASSLOADERS, Collections.singleton(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));
                emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test", properties);
            }
            return emf;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
        {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
            return transactionManager;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ShallowEtagHeaderFilter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() 
        {
            return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleRepository.java

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "simples", path = "simples")
public interface SimpleRepository  extends JpaRepository<Simple, Long>
{
}
```

Simple.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIMPLE")
public class Simple
{
    @JsonCreator
    public Simple(@JsonProperty("changeable") String changeable)
    {
        this.changeable = changeable;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID", sequenceName = "ID", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private int version;
    
    @Column(name = "CHANGEABLE")
    private String changeable;
}
```

It works perfectly with just these three classes, I can interact with the exposed JPA repository via postman, the version number is shipped in the http header as an ETag.

Now I want to extend it for a parent-child-relationship where the version is only incremented in the parent entity.

Parent.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent
{
    @JsonCreator
    public Parent(@JsonProperty("changeable") String changeable)
    {
        this.changeable = changeable;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PARENT_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PARENT_ID", sequenceName = "PARENT_ID", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private int version;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    
    @Column(name = "CHANGEABLE")
    private String changeable;
}
```

Child.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CHILD_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CHILD_ID", sequenceName = "CHILD_ID", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Long id;
    
//  NO VERSION! Parent version should be incremented on change  
//  @Version
//  @Column(name = "VERSION")
//  private int version;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
    
    @Column(name = "CHANGEABLE")
    private String changeable;
}
```

You can find the full example on http://github.com/Meini777/example

What is the best way to implement it? I could code a @RestController on my own instead of using the implicit one from @RepositoryRestResource, but in this case i have implement all the behavior including HATEOAS and ALPS.

Comment: can you make a small reproducer in github for this scenario ? where we can investogate further.

Comment: @özkanpakdil i added a github link

Comment: Did you by chance read this article regarding optimistic force increment? https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic_force_increment-lock-mode-work/ - I believe this could help in your case as you already mentioned in your post.

Comment: @Ely yes I already read that in the past, it's the combination with rest which gives me headaches

Comment: There are few posts similar to your question. I came on
 this article and may solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381416/1604503

Comment: @fukit0 thankm you, this could actually be a great solution for my problem, i just have to make sure the version from the parent object gets transfered via rest to the client

Comment: You're welcome! I hope that will help.

Comment: Can you share the result of your fix?

Comment: I ended up implementing my own RestController instead of using RepositoryRestResource which turned out not to be a big deal, even adding hateoas links is pretty easy. I used the RootAware solution from vladmihalcea but i had some problems with the 2LC so i implemented a Service layer where i manage the version myself. I will abstract the controllers/services in the next step and reuse it for all the other entities I have to publish via REST with version tags at different locations.